# Scipy - Time almost irrelevant to the number of eigenvalues?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I use [scipy.linalg.eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) to solve the general eigenvalue problem: `K @ u = w * M @ u`, where `K, M` are are the stiffness and mass matrices respectively. They are sparse mathematically, but I stick to `scipy.linalg` and don't use `scipy.sparse.linalg` in the code, 'cause it's not efficient with their current size. Should it be like that?
What startled me is that when I tried to test the speed of the function, not only was it slower than expected, but the elapsed time was somewhat irrelevant to the number of the eigenvalues.

```py
stiffness_matrix
>> array([[ 3.80765476e+03,  0.00000000e+00, -2.17580272e+03, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  3.80765476e+03, -2.84217094e-14, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [-2.17580272e+03, -2.84217094e-14,  7.61530952e+03, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         3.80765476e+03, -2.03981505e+02,  1.35987670e+02],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
        -2.03981505e+02,  1.90382738e+03,  6.11944515e+02],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         1.35987670e+02,  6.11944515e+02,  1.90382738e+03]])

# mass_matrix is similar
stiffness_matrix.shape
>>(2100, 2100)

%timeit linalg.eigh(stiffness_matrix, b=mass_matrix, eigvals=(0,1), eigvals_only=True, check_finite=False)
2.39 s ± 124 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit linalg.eigh(stiffness_matrix, b=mass_matrix, eigvals=(0,1000), eigvals_only=True, check_finite=False)
3.02 s ± 71.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**EDIT:** Even if I switch the two matrices and get the max vals instead, it still takes the same amount of time:

```py
linalg.eigh(mass_matrix,
            b=stiffness_matrix, 
            eigvals=(2098, 2099), 
            eigvals_only=True, 
            check_finite=False)
```

As I only need the first 2 eigenvalues, it really gets on my nerves. Is the algorithm so efficient that doesn't escalate with order O(numeigs)? or is the "2-eigenvalues case" so slow, as if it was running with much more eigenvalues? **and most importantly: can I speed it up?**

Comment: what happens if `eigvals=(999,1000)` is used ? 
(looking at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html  eigenvalues are sorted from smallest to largest.  Are you more interested in the smaller or larger eigen values?)

Comment: I am intrested in the smallest, I tried switching the matrices and then get the largest ones, but the  performance was the same. I might add the results.

Comment: @mathewgunther, nothing changes, it's the same.

Comment: I think that eigvals may only affect the returned values, not the calculated ones. Also, from testing, it looks like only eigvals_only is giving a speed-up, but you may want to give turbo, overwrite_a and overwrite_b a try. Also, the sparse version is not giving you any better speeds [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh)?

Comment: @Patol75 I have tried everything except turbo, because it recquires all the eigenvalues I think. I will give it a try, though. As for the sparse library, it does not really help, as I was originally using this and switched to non-sparse. It requires arrays to be converted to sparse format, which takes a little bit, but mainly it seems the arrays are not large/sparse enough to be efficient.

Comment: Well, it is difficult to suggest anything more without the possibility of playing with the arrays myself. But again, it sounds plausible eigvals only selects which eigenvalues to return, not to calculate, and this would be why you see such a small time difference between asking for 2 or 2000 eigenvalues.

Comment: I tried the sparse library and here are the results: When you want the 2 smallest eigenvalues it takes about t_smallest = 10 sec. This is what I have been trying until now. But then, I switched the order of matrices, and then solving for the largest it takes t_largest = 0.01 atmost.  So, the algorithm must be calculating the eigenvalues from largest to smallest, irrelevant of what you ask. This means, that when you want the smallest, it calculates all of the biggers first.

Comment: So I think @Patol75, you were right.

Comment: No worries, happy you found a way.